# Get Generic Type in Constructor in java

Tags: java, generics, reflection, constructor, generic-programming

Is there a way to find generic type in constructor?

```
 public class geneticarg {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    a<String> a1 = new a<String>("a");
    a<String> a2 = new a<String>(null); // gives NPE
    System.out.println(a1.getClazz());
    }
}

class a<T> {

private Class<T> clazz;
private T element;

public a(T clazz) {
this.clazz = (Class<T>) clazz.getClass();
this.element = clazz;
// what if clazz is null ?

}
//getter and setter
}
```

**EDIT** : It is not necessary that always String comes.

Comment: not possible due to type erasure http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html

Comment: can reflection do some magic here?

Comment: generic types are erased by the compiler

Comment: not only does it not work for `null`, but if you pass an instance of a subclass of `T`, it will give you an incorrect class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way to avoid type erasure in your case is to use generic superclass. You need to subclass your generic type and then you can access parametrized type, it is available via reflection API:

```
public abstract class a<T> {

    private Class<T> clazz;
    private T element;

    public a(T obj) {
        ParameterizedType type = (ParameterizedType) this.getClass().getGenericSuperclass();
        this.clazz = (Class<T>) type.getActualTypeArguments()[0];
        this.element = obj;
    }
}

class StringA extends a<String> {
    public StringA(String obj) {
        super(obj);
    }
}
```

Comment: You could have simply done `this.clazz = (Class<T>) obj.getClass()` in the constructor.

Comment: you will get NPE when null is passed, look at the 4th line of the question

Comment: ok got it, +1 for teaching me :) And while the introspection works, the need for it suggests a design problem.

Comment: well, this is a common pattern when you design DAO for Hibernate, there are lots of other useful scenarios when you can use this technique

Comment: Passing in the Class as a parameter of the constructor would also work (which is basically Peter's answer). Note also that your solution won't work for `class GenericSubclassOfA<T> extends a<T>`

Answer (score 4):

You have to pass the type in the constructor.  You can use a static factor to avoid having to set it twice.

```
A<String> a1 = A.wrap("a");
A<String> a2 = A.forClass(String.class);

class A<T> {
    private final Class<T> clazz;
    private final T element;

    private A(T t, Class<T> clazz) {
        this.clazz = clazz;
        this.element = t;
    }

    public static <T> A<T> wrap(T t) {
        return new A<T>(t, (Class) t.getClass());
    }

    public static <T> A<T> forClass(Class<T> clazz) {
        return new A<T>(null, clazz);
    }

    //getter and setter
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Peter is quite correct. I'd like to add some more info:

The instance of `Class<T>` passed into the constructor is called a *type token*.